# how to run cron jobs on GMT not local time?

Tags: time, cron, crontab, time-zone

How can I make cron jobs run on GMT, not local time?

this is my crontab file:

```
#m  h           d   m   wday    command
TZ=GMT
5   0,6,12,18   *   *   *   ~/Documents/bash/transfer.sh
```

my jobs seem to be running at the local time (GMT+11)
I am running os x snow leopard, but will move the code onto linux when development is complete.

The linux environment may be a shared environment where I may has less control over configuration.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/how-do-you-set-the-timezone-for-crontab

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195818/change-the-time-zone-of-a-cronjob

Answer (score 9):

Not all versions of `cron` support running jobs using a time zone other than the system's.

If yours does, it's likely that the specification should be `TZ=GMT` or `TZ=UTC` (without the angle brackets). In some cases, the variable would be `CRON_TZ`.

The best thing to do is check the documentation specific to the particular system. See `man 5 crontab`.

Answer (score 4):

If your local time is `Europe/London`. Then:

```
crontab -e    # or 'cru' on some machines
>>>
# Run COMMAND at 03:15am UTC every morning
15 3 * * * [ "$(date +\%z)" = "+0000" ] && COMMAND
15 4 * * * [ "$(date +\%z)" = "+0100" ] && COMMAND
<<<
```

Another example:

If your regular time is `+0500` shift of `UTC`, and your seasonal time is `+0600` shift of `UTC`. Then add `+5` to all of the hours specified in above example. This means being run at `08:15am` and `09:15am` of your local time respectively. So your modified cron lines would then look like this:

```
crontab -e    # or 'cru' on some machines
>>>
# Run COMMAND at 03:15am UTC every morning
15 8 * * * [ "$(date +\%z)" = "+0500" ] && COMMAND
15 9 * * * [ "$(date +\%z)" = "+0600" ] && COMMAND
<<<
```

[EDIT] Be sure to `\` escape any percent `%` characters in your crontab file. As crontab interprets them to be a newline seperator. e.g. `%` --> `\%`.

Comment: there will be problems if you are in time zone which uses DST so (for example) your timezone is sometimes +01:00 and somethimes +02:00

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate? I don't think so. We already account for DST. Each case has it's own cron line. 1 for each with / without DST.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, as it allows for individiul commands different behaviors

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps could wrap the original crond binary.

```
mv /usr/sbin/crond /usr/sbin/crond.real
cat > /usr/sbin/crond
#!/bin/sh
TZ=GMT
export TZ
exec crond.real ${1+"$@"}
```

Comment: hello hlovdal, could you please explain these steps?

Comment: Are you copying crond to crond.real, then replacing crond with a short script, in which you set and export TZ, then execute crond.real?

Comment: Not copying but moving, but yes the rest of your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run a job every 3 hours but using UTC time and my platform doesn't support using CRON_TZ. My solution was a variation on one of the other answers:

```
0 * * * * [ "$(($(TZ=UTC date +\%H) \% 3))" -eq 0 ] && COMMAND
```

This will run once per hour and then determine if it's the *right* hour.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1088129)